# OpenBSD 6.x usb installer can't find pkg sets

Tags: openbsd

For some reason the OpenBSD 6.2 installer needs the base packages to be in "6.2/amd64" but these directories are not found by the installer. I think I might need to mount a disk partition manually but I can't figure out which one. Any clues would be appreciated. Burning CDs in 2018 seems silly.

Comment: If I mount the usb stick on another system, the sets are exactly where they should be, /6.2/amd64.